# How to invoke a MATLAB script in runtime by its name

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have 3 m-codes:

```
code1.m code2.m code3.m
```

and I want a code for MATLAB to "draw them together" in the sense that when we run the program, we are prompted with, say, "`enter code:`", then the user types in say "`code3`" and then `code3.m` is run.

I am pretty sure there is a simple code to do that, though I can't remember it.

Comment: Load is the one you are looking for when trying to include more files to your code. Then you'll just need the input from user. Look at the example 1: http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two portions to this question, the first of which is getting user input:
Matlab allows you to request user input as shown in this tutorial: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html

```
strResponse = input(prompt, 's')
```

Part two is simply loading the file and executing it, as described by @MetalRain
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html

```
eval(['load code' strResponse '.m'])
```

Noting that matlab perform string concatanation on the vector for you, so the result for the input of `strResponse = 1` is `'load code1.m'`

Comment: The OP asked for a `.m` not a `.mat` (but the principle is the same)

Answer (score 1):

[`run`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/run.html) or [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) can do it. You get the name of the file from [`input`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/input.html).

A (maybe) less flexible but safer method is to use the graphical version of `input` named [`inputdlg`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/listdlg.html).

Comment: If a graphical solution is acceptable, inputdlg is a very nice way to do it, the link provided is a clear and simple tutorial and evan or run can then be used, as described in both answers.